# Ansible provisioning ERROR! Using a SSH password instead of a key is not possible

Tags: ssh, vagrant, ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to provision with my three nodes from the last one by using Ansible.

My host machine is Windows 10.

My Vagrantfile looks like:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  (1..3).each do |index|
    config.vm.define "node#{index}" do |node|

      node.vm.box = "ubuntu"
      node.vm.box = "../boxes/ubuntu_base.box"

      node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.10.#{10 + index}"

      if index == 3
        node.vm.provision :setup, type: :ansible_local do |ansible|
          ansible.playbook = "playbook.yml"
          ansible.provisioning_path = "/vagrant/ansible"
          ansible.inventory_path = "/vagrant/ansible/hosts"
          ansible.limit = :all
          ansible.install_mode = :pip
          ansible.version = "2.0"
        end
      end

    end
  end

end
```

My playbook looks like:

```yaml
---

# my little playbook

- name: My little playbook
  hosts: webservers
  gather_facts: false
  roles:
    - create_user
```

My hosts file looks like:

```ini
[webservers]
192.168.10.11
192.168.10.12

[dbservers]
192.168.10.11
192.168.10.13

[all:vars]
ansible_connection=ssh
ansible_ssh_user=vagrant
ansible_ssh_pass=vagrant
```

After executing `vagrant up --provision` I got the following error:

```
Bringing machine 'node1' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node2' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
Bringing machine 'node3' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> node3: Running provisioner: setup (ansible_local)...
    node3: Running ansible-playbook...

PLAY [My little playbook] ******************************************************

TASK [create_user : Create group] **********************************************
fatal: [192.168.10.11]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! Using a SSH password instead of a key is not possible because Host Key checking is enabled and sshpass does not support this.  Please add this host's fingerprint to your known_hosts file to manage this host."}
fatal: [192.168.10.12]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "ERROR! Using a SSH password instead of a key is not possible because Host Key checking is enabled and sshpass does not support this.  Please add this host's fingerprint to your known_hosts file to manage this host."}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.10.11              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
192.168.10.12              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1

Ansible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

I extended my Vagrantfile with `ansible.limit = :all` and added `[all:vars]` to the hostfile, but still cannot get through the error.

Has anyone encountered the same issue?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Create a file `ansible/ansible.cfg` in your project directory (i.e. `ansible.cfg` in the `provisioning_path` on the target) with the following contents:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = false
```

---

<sup>provided that your Vagrant box has `sshpass` already installed - it's unclear, because the error message in your question suggests it was installed (otherwise it would be "*ERROR! to use the 'ssh' connection type with passwords, you must install the sshpass program*"), but in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42462846/2947502) you add it explicitly (`sudo apt-get install sshpass`), like it was not</sup>

Comment: It might be confusing for some guys, so please put your ansible.cfg in the same folder as your inventry then run it.

Comment: `ansible.cfg` file location is `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Answer (score 65):

I'm using Ansible version 2.6.2 and solution with `host_key_checking = false` doesn't work.

Adding environment variable `export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` skipping fingerprint check.

Comment: This is strange as `host_key_checking` is still referenced in [the latest (2.9) doc](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#host-key-checking)

Comment: Ok, there  is an open issue about this: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49254

Comment: work like a champ.

Answer (score 29):

This error can also be solved by simply export `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` variable.

```
export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False
```

source: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/9442

Comment: but where to write it

Answer (score 8):

run  the below command, it resolved my issue

**export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False**  &&  ansible-playbook -i

Answer (score 6):

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297187/multi-machine-ansible-setup-with-vagrant-on-windows) gave the answer.

I just extended the known_hosts file on the machine that is responsible for the provisioning like this:

Snippet from my modified Vagrantfile:

```ruby
...
if index == 3
    node.vm.provision :pre, type: :shell, path: "install.sh"

    node.vm.provision :setup, type: :ansible_local do |ansible|
...
```

My install.sh looks like:

```sh
# add web/database hosts to known_hosts (IP is defined in Vagrantfile)
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.10.11 >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.10.12 >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.10.13 >> /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts
chown vagrant:vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts

# reload ssh in order to load the known hosts
/etc/init.d/ssh reload
```

Comment: shellscripting workaround. Ansible ensures a better way though!

Comment: To be clear this is all a problem from Vagrant's side via https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/5005, and while inconvenient, security-wise this is actually the correct approach, and the others are actually the workaround.

For local development purposes totally go with the simpler disable checking, I don't mean to come across fussy or pedantic, just feel it might be good to clarify for users who are newer to things to be aware of the security implications. I'm just fearing calling it the better way might mislead some. :)

Comment: I am not sure it is worth a new answer at this date, but I just noticed at the official docs for Ansible and Vagrant on Ansible's side https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_vagrant.html#vagrant-setup they recommend the vagrant config line `config.ssh.insert_key = false`. Probably easier than ENV vars or .cfg manipulation.

Comment: @JasmineHegman, Thank you for the update! I agree on that Vagrant config is much convenient and much safer than ENV var or the .cfg.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar challenge when working with **Ansible 2.9.6** on **Ubuntu 20.04**.

When I run the command:

```
ansible all -m ping -i inventory.txt
```

I get the error:

> target | FAILED! => {
> "msg": "Using a SSH password instead of a key is not possible because Host Key checking is enabled and sshpass does not support this.  Please add this host's fingerprint to your known_hosts file to manage this host."
> }

**Here's how I fixed it**:

When you install ansible, it creates a file called `ansible.cfg`, this can be found in the `/etc/ansible` directory. Simply open the file:

```
sudo nano /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
```

Uncomment this line to disable SSH key host checking

```
host_key_checking = False
```

Now save the file and you should be fine now.

**Note**: You could also try to add the host's fingerprint to your `known_hosts` file by SSHing into the server from your machine, this prompts you to save the host's fingerprint to your `known_hosts` file:

```
promisepreston@ubuntu:~$ ssh myusername@192.168.43.240

The authenticity of host '192.168.43.240 (192.168.43.240)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:9Zib8lwSOHjA9khFkeEPk9MjOE67YN7qPC4mm/nuZNU.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.43.240' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

myusername@192.168.43.240's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-53-generic x86_64)
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 6):

all provided solutions require changes in global config file or adding environment variable what create problems to onboard new people.

Instead you can add following variable to your inventory or host vars

```
ansible_ssh_common_args: '-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Comment: Perfect answer for my problem

Answer (score 3):

Adding ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
to either your inventory

like:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'

[all:children]
servers

[servers]
host1
```

OR:

```
[servers]
host1 ansible_ssh_common_args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).